# count row if date falls within date range for all dates in series in R

Tags: r, date, count, intervals, date-range

I have a large data frame (~30,000 rows) where I have two date fields "start_date" and "end_date".

I want to summarise the data such that I have 1 column with all the dates and a second column with a count of all the rows in which that date is between the "start_date" and "end_date".

I can make this work using 2 for loops but it is very inefficient as it is going by one though one comparing about 180 dates to 30,000 rows of date ranges.

Below is an example. Say I have the following dataframe.

```
df <- tibble(
  start_date = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5),
  end_date = c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
)
```

I want this to output a table/dataframe that looks like this

```
Date    Count
1       2
2       4
3       5
4       6
5       7
6       6
7       5
8       4
9       3
10      2
11      1
```

Is there some TidyVerse functions or anything else that could do this transformation efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a base R method:

```
date = seq(min(df$start_date), max(df$end_date))
count = sapply(date, \(x) sum(x >= df$start_date & x <= df$end_date))
data.frame(date, count)
#    date count
# 1     1     2
# 2     2     4
# 3     3     5
# 4     4     6
# 5     5     7
# 6     6     6
# 7     7     5
# 8     8     4
# 9     9     3
# 10   10     2
# 11   11     1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `data.table` approach using `foverlaps`. First, create a `seq`uence of desired dates from the minimum `start_date` to the maximum `end_date`. Then, create a simple `data.table` for each of these dates.

Use `foverlaps` to get the overlapping join between your starting data.frame and the new table. Finally, count up the number of rows after the join for each date.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
dates <- seq(min(df$start_date), max(df$end_date), by = 1)
dt <- data.table(start_date = dates, end_date = dates, key = c("start_date", "end_date"))
foverlaps(df, dt, which = T)[, .N, by = yid]
```

**Output**

```
    yid N
 1:   1 2
 2:   2 4
 3:   3 5
 4:   4 6
 5:   5 7
 6:   6 6
 7:   7 5
 8:   8 4
 9:   9 3
10:  10 2
11:  11 1
```

In `tidyverse` you could adapt to the following:

```
library(tidyverse)

data.frame(date = seq(min(df$start_date), max(df$end_date), by = 1)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(count = sum(date >= df$start_date & date <= df$end_date))
```