# Computing number of participants by timepoints

Tags: r, frequency, proportions

I have a short question about computing the number of participants by timepoints. Consider the sample long format data:

```
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),survey_date=c("01/12/2020","02/12/2020","03/12/2020","04/12/2020","01/31/2020","03/12/2020","04/05/2020","02/12/2020","04/12/2020","05/12/2020","06/12/2020"),last_seen=c('05/25/2020','05/25/2020','05/25/2020','05/25/2020','04/06/2020','04/06/2020','04/06/2020','','','',''))
```

Survey date indicates when the survey took place. \Some subjects in the data became lost to follow-up, we do have that last-seen date recorded in the data for those subjects (it appears in all rows for that subject).

I would like to add a column 'num_N' to the existing data indicating the number of participants who were in the study at the timepoint survey_date.

For example, on 01/12/2020, only subject id=1 was in the study, so num_N for that row would be 1. 
On 06/12/2020, only subject id=3 was in the study, so num_N for that row would be 1.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for something like `dplyr::add_count(data, survey_date)`?

Comment: Not quite, the add_count function does not compute the count I anticipated. For example, on 01/31/2020, both id=1 and 2 are in the study, but add_count would give a 1 for that row.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why id1 is in the study on 01/31/2020?

Comment: @Maël - based on the OP, id1 enters the study on 01/12/2020 and leaves it on 05/25/2020.  01/31/2020 is within this range even though they don't have an entry for that date.

Comment: I see, sorry for duplicating too fast, I'll vote for reopening

Comment: This question is definitely not duplicate since date is involved and it's not just simple counts. Let's say the study period is the entire year of 2020. Once the subject enters the study, he/she is considered as "in the study" until lost to follow up. So on 01/31/2020 id1 would still be considered as in the study.

Comment: So for id3, the period is from 02/12 to 06/12?

Comment: @Maël Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Sounds more like a dup of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26290314/r-calculate-a-count-of-items-over-time-using-start-and-end-dates or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966129/count-row-if-date-falls-within-date-range-for-all-dates-in-series-in-r

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a good case for `iv_count_between` from `ivs`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ivs)

#Convert your dates to date format
data <- data |> 
  mutate(across(-id, lubridate::mdy)) 

#Create intervals
data_ivs <- 
  data |> 
  summarise(min = min(survey_date), 
            max = max(survey_date, last_seen, na.rm = TRUE), 
            .by = id) |> 
  mutate(ivs = iv(min, max + 1))

#Count intervals with `iv_count_between`:
data |> 
  mutate(num_N = iv_count_between(survey_date, data_ivs$ivs))

#    id survey_date  last_seen num_N
# 1   1  2020-01-12 2020-05-25     1
# 2   1  2020-02-12 2020-05-25     3
# 3   1  2020-03-12 2020-05-25     3
# 4   1  2020-04-12 2020-05-25     2
# 5   2  2020-01-31 2020-04-06     2
# 6   2  2020-03-12 2020-04-06     3
# 7   2  2020-04-05 2020-04-06     3
# 8   3  2020-02-12       <NA>     3
# 9   3  2020-04-12       <NA>     2
# 10  3  2020-05-12       <NA>     2
# 11  3  2020-06-12       <NA>     1
```

Answer (score 3):

First things first. When dealing with strings representing dates in R, you need to convert these to actual date objects in order to perform arithmetic or logical tests on them. For your case, I would also convert the `NA` values in the last column into some date in the future of the last survey date (for example today's date):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(across(-id, ~as.Date(.x, format = '%m/%d/%Y'))) %>%
  mutate(last_seen = if_else(is.na(last_seen), Sys.Date(), last_seen))
```

Now your data looks like this:

```r
data2
#>    id survey_date  last_seen
#> 1   1  2020-01-12 2020-05-25
#> 2   1  2020-02-12 2020-05-25
#> 3   1  2020-03-12 2020-05-25
#> 4   1  2020-04-12 2020-05-25
#> 5   2  2020-01-31 2020-04-06
#> 6   2  2020-03-12 2020-04-06
#> 7   2  2020-04-05 2020-04-06
#> 8   3  2020-02-12 2023-10-24
#> 9   3  2020-04-12 2023-10-24
#> 10  3  2020-05-12 2023-10-24
#> 11  3  2020-06-12 2023-10-24
```

From this we can construct a little lookup table

```r
lookup <- data2 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(first_date = min(survey_date), 
            last_date  = first(last_seen))
```

And we can get the number of participants at each survey date using simple logical tests:

```r
data2 <- data2 %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(num_N = sum(survey_date >= lookup$first_date &
                     survey_date <= lookup$last_date))
```

So your data looks like this:

```r
data2
#> # A tibble: 11 x 4
#> # Rowwise: 
#>       id survey_date last_seen  num_N
#>    <dbl> <date>      <date>     <int>
#>  1     1 2020-01-12  2020-05-25     1
#>  2     1 2020-02-12  2020-05-25     3
#>  3     1 2020-03-12  2020-05-25     3
#>  4     1 2020-04-12  2020-05-25     2
#>  5     2 2020-01-31  2020-04-06     2
#>  6     2 2020-03-12  2020-04-06     3
#>  7     2 2020-04-05  2020-04-06     3
#>  8     3 2020-02-12  2023-10-24     3
#>  9     3 2020-04-12  2023-10-24     2
#> 10     3 2020-05-12  2023-10-24     2
#> 11     3 2020-06-12  2023-10-24     1
```

If you really wanted to, you could add this final column back into your original data:

```r
within(data, num_N <- data2$num_N)
#>    id survey_date  last_seen num_N
#> 1   1  01/12/2020 05/25/2020     1
#> 2   1  02/12/2020 05/25/2020     3
#> 3   1  03/12/2020 05/25/2020     3
#> 4   1  04/12/2020 05/25/2020     2
#> 5   2  01/31/2020 04/06/2020     2
#> 6   2  03/12/2020 04/06/2020     3
#> 7   2  04/05/2020 04/06/2020     3
#> 8   3  02/12/2020                3
#> 9   3  04/12/2020                2
#> 10  3  05/12/2020                2
#> 11  3  06/12/2020                1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a ridiculously convoluted method.

Prepare the provided data:

```
library(tidyverse)
data<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),survey_date=c("01/12/2020","02/12/2020","03/12/2020","04/12/2020","01/31/2020","03/12/2020","04/05/2020","02/12/2020","04/12/2020","05/12/2020","06/12/2020"),last_seen=c('05/25/2020','05/25/2020','05/25/2020','05/25/2020','04/06/2020','04/06/2020','04/06/2020','','','',''))

data <- data |> mutate(across(2:3, \(x) as.Date(x,format = "%m/%d/%Y")))
# set the date formats
```

Next, prepare a table of participant start/end dates:

```
data_ranges <- data |> mutate(first_seen = min(survey_date),
               last_seen = if_else(!is.na(last_seen),
                                   last_seen,
                                   max(survey_date)),
               .by = id) |> 
  select(-survey_date) |> 
  distinct()
```

Next, prepare a helper table with every date between the earliest start and the latest departure from the study, and count how many of the participants bracket that date:

```
data2 <- tibble(
  date = seq(from = min(data$survey_date),
             to = max(c(data$survey_date, data$last_seen), na.rm = TRUE),
             by = "days"),
  n = sapply(date, 
             \(date) nrow(filter(data_ranges, first_seen <= date & last_seen >= date)))
)
```

and combine the datasets:

```
left_join(data, data2, by = c("survey_date" = "date"))  

   id survey_date  last_seen n
1   1  2020-01-12 2020-05-25 1
2   1  2020-02-12 2020-05-25 3
3   1  2020-03-12 2020-05-25 3
4   1  2020-04-12 2020-05-25 2
5   2  2020-01-31 2020-04-06 2
6   2  2020-03-12 2020-04-06 3
7   2  2020-04-05 2020-04-06 3
8   3  2020-02-12       <NA> 3
9   3  2020-04-12       <NA> 2
10  3  2020-05-12       <NA> 2
11  3  2020-06-12       <NA> 1
```

I am not happy with this as a 'final' version - in particular, the sapply seems very slow and unweildy, but I'm out of time I'm afraid!